# Retrieving a variable and passing it to a different class

Tags: java, variables

I have created an averaging program where the `average` variable contains the average. I want the value to be printed out in my graphical user interface, but my GUI is in a different class.

I cant seem to get the variable "average" working in my different class. I'm getting "cannot find symbol" average - no matter what I try. Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("this is the average: "+ average);
// this perfectly prints out the average from the
// class "public void test" and the method "calcAverage"

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    // this is my button in a different class where I want
    // my average to append to (print to the GUI) - and my
    // obviously non-working attempt at it
    JTextArea.append (test.calcAverage(average));
}
```

Comment: What is your error message? What behaviour are you getting, and what is your expected output? Do you have a method in your `test` class that returns the average (such as a method `getAverage()`)?

Comment: Your GUI class will need to ask this class for the variable. Something like `myClass1.getAverage()` and then in Class1 you would have a method which returns the variable.

Comment: When I create a method in my test class of getAverage() it has the error "cannot find symbol - variable average "    - this is all I have, is this wrong?  '  public double getAverage(){
return average;
}  '

Answer (score 0):

> I want the average to be printed out in my graphical user interface,
>   but my gui is in a different class.

Make the gui class provide a callback method to allow to update visually the information.

In Swing :

```
public MyFrame extends JFrame implements MyFrameCallback{

   public void updateAverage(double average){
       ... // update the graphical widget 
   }
}
```

where `MyFrameCallback` is an interface such as :

```
public interface MyFrameCallback{
   void updateAverage(double average);
}
```

Now as you create the model class that we will call `MyAverageModel`, add `MyFrameCallback` in its constructor :

```
public MyAverageModel (MyFrameCallback myFrameCallback){
   this.myFrameCallback = myFrameCallback;
}
```

Now as you calculate the average in `MyAverageModel`, you can invoke the callback of the gui :

```
public calculAndUpdateAverage(){
   ...
   double average = ...;
   myFrameCallback.updateAverage(average);
}
```

Comment: Tried doing this and there's errors everywhere. Surely it's much simpler than this to simply print out a variable somewhere else. Thanks for your time nonetheless.

Comment: I gave you a clean way. You can also make a quick and dirty way : make `calcAverage()` public static.